# What happens if your manuscript is accepted as a filler?

Tags: soft-question, advice, publishing

I just got a responce from a journal of the MAA that my manuscript is accepted as a filler.
The email says :

> "The Editorial Board likes your submission and has asked me to move it
>   to the "Filler Archives." Filler pieces are used only on a space
>   available basis. Hence, it is now in a queue with other filler pieces
>   awaiting publication. It is impossible for us to predict if or when we
>   will use it, but if an opportunity to publish it arises, then we will
>   let you know. If you choose to publish it somewhere else, please
>   inform us so that I can remove it from the archives".

So, what should i expect?
Since it is impossible to predict "if or when" they will use it this could mean that I might wait "forever"?
I am a little bit confused, and I would like if anybody has any similar experience to give me some advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably a better question for academia.SE.

Comment: [Also posted on Academia.SE.](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19164/what-happens-if-your-manuscript-is-accepted-as-a-filler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful information to get is to ask MAA how many articles are currently in their filler archive. That together with how many articles they publish per issue will give you some idea of your chances.

Here is an algorithm if they don't give you more information. Wait for 6 months. If it has not be published by MAA by then ask them about it again. Repeat one time then publish it somewhere else.

I am assuming that it is far more important to publish in journal of the MAA than in another journal. If not, then immediately submit it to another journal. If you want to take a risk then only tell the MAA if the second journal accepts it.

I have not had this situation personally so just giving you some ideas that might help.